# How to migrate the business Gmail DNS record from GoDaddy to AWS Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, g-suite, godaddy

the title of this question might be confusing. So my issue is I have registered a domain in Godaddy, and setup the business gmail using that domain. Recently I decided to migrate the DNS from Godaddy to AWS Route53, and I still want my business email to work as usual.

There are some `MX records` and `TXT records` already exist in Godaddy's DNS management page for email and domain verification, do I need to put those records in the AWS Route53? Do I need to verify the domain again since the domain host is changed from Godaddy to AWS?

Comment: If you want to be safe, just copy everything as-it-is. Route53 is not meant to be use for simple websites. If you are unsure what you are doing, maybe you should just stay away from Route53.

Comment: @VarunAgw Route53 is a DNS server like any other, just with some convenient integrations with other AWS services and a *very* reliable architecture. Not sure why you made this comment.

Comment: @MLu Personally I just feel it can be overwhelming and unnecessary for someone looking for something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating a domain from one set of DNS servers to another takes several steps:

1. Create the domain in Route53
2. In Route53 **create all the records** that are currently in GoDaddy except NS and SOA. These are managed by Amazon. All the other records must be recreated in AWS. Including MX, TXT, A, etc.
3. Go to GoDaddy domain management and **change the nameservers** to the 4 servers found in the Route53 NS records. They will be in a form ns-123.awsdns-456.com/.org/.etc.
4. Wait at least a day for everything to propagate. However since the content of the zone is now the same in both GoDaddy and in Route53 it doesn’t really matter how long it takes.
5. Once done you can also **transfer the domain to Route53 registrar**, that means you’ll start paying the annual fee to AWS and not to GoDaddy.

And no, you won’t have to re-verify the domain at Google as long as you copy all the TXT and MX records across.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I've just found some helpful links about transferring the DNS record: https://support.google.com/a/answer/6149697?hl=en and transfer domain registrar: https://blog.shikisoft.com/transferring-domain-registrations-from-godaddy-to-amazon-route-53/